# How do I put an `std::string` into a Clang virtual file?

Tags: c++, clang

I have an `std::string` of C++ code that I would like to process using Clang.

I understand that this requires it to be put into a `clang::FileManager` so that it can be accessed by a `clang::SoureManager`. I would like to avoid writing to disk so I will be using virtual files.

How do I put my `std::string` into a new virtual file?

Comment: why does the type `std::string` matter? Outside of C++, it has no meaning.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I am working in C++. `std::string` is the return type of another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, that's quit straightforward:

1, build a [llvm MemoryBuffer](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MemoryBuffer.html) from the content of your std::string
2, call [clang::SourceManager::createFileID](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a941f1bd97c6d84e31065f653bbc2c2c5) to get a FileID which is exactly what you want.